# How to find the last occurring target letter in a string?

Tags: python, string, find, slice, target

So there is a string and the question is asking me to find the last occurring target letter that I input. Then, I have to print string from the last occurring target letter that I got to the end of the string.

I only learned `x.find()` and `x.rfind()`, `x.strip()`, `x.split()`, and `x.splitlines()`.

Another condition is that the strings have to be converted into lowercase letters and string has two `\n` in the middle and at the end.

So far I have this:

```
text = text.strip().lower
target = input("target: ")
```

and I don't know where to go next.

Comment: If you already know `x.find()` and `x.rfind()` you have the tools to identify where the last occurrence of your target letter is. Then you can use slicing to get the string that you want.

Comment: Also, it would be better if you posted an example showing a sample string, target letter, and the desired output. For example, you mention that there is a `\n` in the middle, but I'm not sure why that's relevant? And, `.lower` is a method, so it should be `.lower()` - the brackets will cause the method to execute and convert `text` to lower case.

Comment: yes I realized \n does not really matter for this question... but thank you for the hint!!

Comment: Great. For your next question, though, it would be much clearer if you added a *For Example* and then demonstrated what you wanted to achieve. It's much clearer than just describing it.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the text from the last target founded to the end of the text

```
text = text[text.rfind(target):]
```

The rfind will found the last occurrence of the target in a string and the slicing is taking the index that the target word start and will slice the text from that point until the end of the string since no number is following after the :

Comment: Tnx for that added some explanations

Comment: Welcome to SO. glad to help if that is the answer that you looked for please mark it as answered and vote up.

Comment: @DavidBuck Thanks for that I will consider this advice on my next answers from beginners.

Comment: @bang21 Did it helped?